# In RethinkDB, does `group` preserve the ordering of the original stream?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a query that looks like:

```
r.table.orderBy(someIndex).group("someField")
```

Will the elements in each grouped stream be sorted by `someIndex` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `group` should preserve the ordering of the stream it was called on.